# Angularjs json data table repeat based on condition

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have a small task of creating a table from the json which im getting it from the webservice using angularjs

Creating a normal table is working fine for me but based on the type , i have to do a col span . for example

if type is Manufacture then no col span
 
if type is Product then i have to merger all 3 columns
if type is Summary then the i have to merge first 2 columns

Please note that this code does not work because i have to remove Type Product andManufacturer.

Please help me to format the output as like shown below

```
*-------------------------------*   
| Manufacturer | Rate  | Disc%  | 
+--------------|-------|--------+
| Product A                     |
|--------------+-------+--------|
| Manuf.A      | 500   | 2      |
|--------------+-------+--------|
| Manuf.b      | 450   | 0      |
|--------------+-------+--------|
| Manuf.c      | 400   | 1      |
|--------------+-------+--------|
| No of Suppliers      | 3      |
+-------------------------------+
```

js

```
 var app = angular.module('Products', []);

 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.array = [
              {"Name":"Product A","Type":"Product"},
              {"Name":"Manufacturer A","Rate":"100","discount":"2%","Type":"Manufacturer"},
              {"Name":"Manufacturer B","Rate":"90","discount":"1%","Type":"Manufacturer"},
              {"Name":"Manufacturer C","Rate":"95","discount":"XXXXXX","Type":"2%"},
              {"Name":"No Of Suppliers","total":"3","Type":"Summary"}];
 });
```

Html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Products">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app1.js"></script>
    <style>
        td 
        {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body ng-Controller="MainCtrl">
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Manufacturer</th>
          <th>Rate</th>
          <th>Disc%</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in array track by $index">
          <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
          <td >{{item.Rate}}</td>
          <td >{{item.discount}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ng-show` for this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in array track by $index">
    <td colspan="3" ng-show="item.Type == 'Product'">{{item.Name}}</td>
    <td colspan="2" ng-show="item.Type == 'Summary'">{{item.Name}}</td>
    <td ng-show="item.Type != 'Product' && item.Type != 'Summary'">{{item.Name}}</td>
    <td ng-show="item.Type != 'Product' && item.Type != 'Summary'">{{item.Rate}}</td>
    <td ng-show="item.Type != 'Product' && item.Type != 'Summary'">{{item.discount}}</td>
    <td ng-show="item.Type == 'Summary'">{{item.total}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` directives:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="item in array track by $index" ng-if="item.Type == 'Manufacturer'">
        <td>{{item.Name}} {{item.Type}}</td>
        <td>{{item.Rate}}</td>
        <td>{{item.discount}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="item.Type == 'Product'">
        <td colspan="3">
            {{item.Name}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="item.Type == 'Summary' ">
        <td colspan="2">{{item.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.total}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/3MPj3okUsi3swJvSfdAr?p=preview